# I have syntax error for macro in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I got syntax error for macro code in excel. Macro code below:

```
Sub concatnate()
'
' concatnate Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=CONCATENATE("","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""& _
        "","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","")"
    Range("C1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Cells.Replace What:=",,", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: i made some changes in code then syntax error resolved but i did not get the exact result new is-

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple, really.

You can't put double quotes INSIDE a set of double quotes.

You need to replace all those inner quotes with double-double quotes

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=CONCATENATE("""","""")"
```

As per comment, this answer has been corrected.

Comment: This is Excel VBA, not ASP Classic or T-SQL. The single quotes are not going to work as an alternative.

Comment: You, sir, are correct.  So I tried a couple of different things.  It seems that double-double quotes is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the VBE is getting a little confused trying to make sense of all those commas. It can be corrected as,

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=CONCATENATE("","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""," & _
                 ""","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","")"
```

If all you want is 99 commas then the following might be better.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=REPT(CHAR(44), 99)"
```